# Networkx: plot quality issue

Tags: python, networkx

Below are two plotted network graph using two methods. The lines and circles in the first graph looks better and smoother than the second one. But I cannot really tell the reason why the second one does not look the same as the first one in terms of the image quality.

```
locations = {
    0:(4,4),
    1:(2,0),
    2:(8,0),
    3:(0,1),
    4:(1,1),
    5:(5,2),
    6:(7,2),
    7:(3,3),
    8:(6,3),
}

edges = [
    (0, 8, {'vehicle': '0'}),
    (8, 6, {'vehicle': '0'}),
    (6, 2, {'vehicle': '0'}),
    (2, 5, {'vehicle': '0'}),
    (5, 0, {'vehicle': '0'}),
    (0, 7, {'vehicle': '1'}),
    (7, 1, {'vehicle': '1'}),
    (1, 4, {'vehicle': '1'}),
    (4, 3, {'vehicle': '1'}),
    (3, 0, {'vehicle': '1'}),
]

G=nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from(edges)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.show()

#vehicle 0
temp = [e for e in edges if e[2]['vehicle'] == '0'] #temporary list that filters the path of vehicle 0
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, locations, nodelist=[x[0] for x in temp], node_color='b')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, locations, edgelist=temp,
                       width=2, edge_color='b', style='dashed')

#vehicle 1
temp = [e for e in edges if e[2]['vehicle'] == '1']
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, locations, nodelist=[x[0] for x in temp], node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, locations, edgelist=temp,
                       width=2, edge_color='r', style='dashed')

#let's color the node 0 in black
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, locations, nodelist=[0], node_color='k')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, locations, font_color='w', font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')

#print out the graph
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The second graph and codes:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

locations = \
    [(4, 4),  # depot
     (2, 0), (8, 0),  # row 0
     (0, 1), (1, 1),
     (5, 2), (7, 2),
     (3, 3), (6, 3),
     (5, 5), (8, 5),
     (1, 6), (2, 6),
     (3, 7), (6, 7),
     (0, 8), (7, 8)]

v0 = [0, 1, 4, 3, 15, 0]
v1 = [0, 14, 16, 10, 2, 0]
vehicles = [v0, v1]
cl = ["r", "b","green","yellow"]

x=0

for v in vehicles:
    n=0
    e=[]
    node=[]
    for i in v:
        G.add_node(i, pos=(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]))
        # a= [locations[i][0], locations[i][1]]
        # print(a)
        if n > 0:
            # print(n)
            # print(v[n])
            # print (v[n-1])
            u= (v[n-1], v[n])
            e.append(u)
            node.append(i)
            print(e)
            print(node)
            G.add_edge(v[n-1], v[n])
            nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), nodelist=node, edgelist=e, with_labels=True, node_color=cl[x], width=2, edge_color=cl[x], \
            style='dashed', font_color='w', font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
            # print(x)
        n += 1
    x+=1
#let's color the node 0 in black
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, locations, nodelist=[0], node_color='k')
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

[image]

when zoomed out (might be not very clear to see here), the lines and circles in the second graph are not as smooth as the first graph. what's the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the same nodes and edges more than once. Call the draw function outside of the node loop:

```
for v in vehicles:
    n=0
    e=[]
    node=[]
    for i in v:
        G.add_node(i, pos=(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]))
        # a= [locations[i][0], locations[i][1]]
        # print(a)
        if n > 0:
            # print(n)
            # print(v[n])
            # print (v[n-1])
            u= (v[n-1], v[n])
            e.append(u)
            node.append(i)
            print(e)
            print(node)
            G.add_edge(v[n-1], v[n])
            # print(x)
        n += 1
    nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), nodelist=node, edgelist=e, with_labels=True, node_color=cl[x], width=2, edge_color=cl[x], \
    style='dashed', font_color='w', font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')
    x+=1
```

Which results in this image:

[image: graph]

Comment: I guess that's potentially where the problem is. But if I move the drawing out of the loop, the node_color function become invalid. I try to input a list of colors but it did not work out nicely.

Comment: @Jack I'm getting the same colors as those in the graph you posted. Note that the index used in the `node_color` function is updated in the vehicles loop (where the call is made now), not the node loop. Are you getting a different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show how `plt` is initialized in the first code snipped. These differences tend to come from the backend used by matplotlib. You may want to take a look at this documentation: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend